# Where we are storing transaction logs in Hyperledger Fabric?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

In general, Ledger is divided into two part into Hyperledger Fabric

1) Transaction Logs

2) World State

I know that we can store world state either into LevelDB or CouchDB, which is configurable.

However; I am bit confused about Transaction Logs. Where hyperledger fabric storing transaction logs into LevelDB or into Files?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The blockchain itself is stored (using LevelDB) in subfolder of the directory defined by the peer.fileSystemPath config value. With a standard setup, the fileSystemPath value is stored in `/etc/hyperledger/fabric/core.yaml`, and the default value is `/var/hyperledger/production`. This results in a location of `/var/hyperledger/production/ledgersData/chains` for the blockchain.

Comment: Thank You Paul. Yes transaction logs are getting stored on each peer, what I would like to know is how its getting stored. In form of Files or in LevelDB?

Comment: Looking at the source, it is using LevelDB.

Comment: This is not correct, the transientStore is a temporary store for private data before it is committed, it does not hold transaction logs.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @DaveEnyeart. I've corrected the location in my answer. Not sure where I got the idea that it was using the transientStore!

Answer (score 1):

In a blockchain such as Hyperledger Fabric, the blockchain itself is the transaction log. In Fabric, the blockchain is stored in the CORE_PEER_FILESYSTEMPATH/ledgersData/chains directory. Look for a series of files called blockfile_XXXXXXX.

By default CORE_PEER_FILESYSTEMPATH is set to /var/hyperledger/production.

Answer (score 0):

The path on local system is var/lib/docker/volumes/net_peer0.org2.example.com/_data/ledgersData/chains/chains/<channel_name>/blockfile_XXXXXX

The path inside docker container is /var/hyperledger/production/ledgersData/chains/chains/mychannel/<channel_name>/blockfile_XXXXXX

This is by default configured in fabric-samples/test-network/docker/docker-compose-test-net.yaml